# No resource found when using style Theme.Sherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I am trying to use Sherlock.
The steps that I did bring up the library of abc to my project while my project min sdk 2.2 and max api 15. the problem is that I can't set up the style to use it.
the error

```
Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/  Theme.Sherlock'.
```

my code of xml:

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock" />

</resources>
```

my manifest file:

```
  <application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

the java that I use is 1.6. I am running 4.0.3 avd.
I know that you will give me a link for webs but I didn't find anything that can help.
I am using eclipse and Sherlock 4.0.3.If you can give me the solution how to do it simple way with instructions.

**update:**
I don't know why but when I do import library abc in my project it looks ok but when I click apply and exit the settings after that return to library, I see red x.

thanks.

Comment: The output says `'@style/  Theme.Sherlock'`, with spaces. Are you perhaps setting your theme within the manifest or app itself, using `__Theme_Sherlock`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"I don't know why but when I do import to library on my project the ABC its with look OK but when I click apply and exit the settings after that return to library and see red x."
This happens when the library file is not in the same workspace or directory as your project is in. 
1.Try copying the library to same workspace, 
2. import it to eclipse 
3. apply it to your project.

I hope that will solve your problem.

and in manifest

```
<application
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock"
>
```

Comment: adding library project to same workspace help resolved the issue. Thanks Atif.

Answer (score -2):

You should set your theme in the manifest

```
<application
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock"
>
```

Comment: did that abd get error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/Theme.Sherlock'). on the theme line

Comment: did u remove that theme under resources tag in xml?

Comment: on style have only this  <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light" />